# SMTP Authentication Exception using Java 8 parallel stream API

Tags: spring, multithreading, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I'm using spring boot based  java mail for sending email by using SMTP relay configuration.I'm using java8 parallel Stream API to send distributed email to enduser.

```
List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100)
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        range.parallelStream().forEach((x) ->
        this.sendSMTPEmail("email@gmail.com", null, null, "smtp  gmail"+x, "hi , how are you",x)
```

After sending few email I have received below error:

```
Mail Exception in sendSMTPEmail {}Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. b21sm1498494pjp.1 - gsmtp
```

I have followed below steps also  but same problem occurred:

1. Login to Gmail.
2. Access the URL as https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Select "Turn on"

Comment: Maybe you are login each time sending email, that cause the problem

Comment: I have used below mechanism to get the session objects from SMTP, "                Session session = ((JavaMailSenderImpl) this.javaMailSender).getSession();" it will return same session for each execution.

Comment: In Java > 8 security engine has been updated are you using Java 8 or a latest version? For java > 8  you need to configure SSL to trust all hosts

Comment: I have tried java 8 and 10 version same problem only occurred.

Comment: This was REALLY useful.  I am having a similar problem with Office365 - anyone know how to turn on the "less secure apps" for that service?